Kick drum not working in electronic drum kit
I have set up my Yamaha dtx 502 kit after long term storage and can't get the kick drum to work. I've tried its cable in other drums and other drums cables in the kick drum but only get silence (when they are plugged in). The strange thing is, when I touch the tip of the kick drum cable I get a rolling kick drum. Also, when I touch the sides of the jack plug I get cymbal sounds!
I have done multiple factory resets and selected various drum kits but the effect is always the same.

1st job, after long term storage, would be to clean all the jacks, and also all the jack sockets - on the drums and on the brain itself. Then check each jack-jack for continuity - tip and sleeve, and ring if there is one, probably on at least one lead.

Have you tried hooking a pad up to the kick input and playing the pad? Sounds like the kick trigger unit might be bad.

The fact that you don't get sound with the "old" cables on another kit could be a symptom of multiple issues: the cables, the pad, its trigger or the control unit (or a combination of them). Note that this assumes that the cables are compatible (using a simple electric tester would help). Note that electronic devices are not immortal, some internal components wear off for various reasons. Since you mainly have 3 separate components (the pad/trigger, the cable and the control unit), then you can try to "debug" with multiple combinations of them in order to exclude each fault possibility.

I never thought that the jack plugs being slightly dirty could be a problem and they look clean. But I will clean them. Also maybe a lump of dirt got into the socket so I'll clean that. I have not plugged in any drums from any other kits. It is the same drum kit that was working perfectly before I dismantled it and stored it. But I am inclined to think that I have to spend £95 for a new kick drum trigger.

We had the drum kit with our Wii. The bass drum pedal was essentially a magnetic reed switch and a magnet.  In ours, the reed switch went bad.  If your pedal is similar, you can check a reed switch with an ohmmeter and a magnet to see if it opens and closes.
